# How to save code snippets (vb/c#/.net/sql) to sql server

Tags: .net, code-snippets

I want to create a code/knowledge base where I can save my vb.net/c#.net/sqlserver code snippets for use later.

I've tried setting the ValidateRequest property to false in my page directive, and encoding the value with HttpUtility.HtmlEncode (c#.net), but I still get errors.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The HttpUtility.HtmlEncode will happen too late, assuming you are getting the exception on postback of code from the client. You can run some javascript on the client to pre-encode the server Postback.

See the following link for a quick example: [Comparing escape(), encodeURI(), and encodeURIComponent()](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)